# Detect if exact number exist in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I have a string could be like this

```
var str = "127";
```

or

```
var str ="127,5,28,12";
```

I want to check if number exist I don't want to add it again. So I use

```
if(!str.includes(id))
     // do so and so
```

But the problem with `includes` is that If I search for 1 it will get it from 127 and that's not accurate. Is there a better way to detect exact number in js?

Comment: If your string always holds a comma separated value, you're better off putting those values in an array.

Comment: @Ja͢ck—"*better off*" how? The string *indexOf* method is more widely supported than the array version, so not by that criterion at least.

Comment: @RobG in the sense that perhaps a string is simply the wrong datatype.

Comment: Ok, I don't know where the OP got the *includes* method from, it seems to be being used as a method of *String.prototype*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
var str ="127,5,28,12";
var exists = str.split(/,/).indexOf("127")

if(exists > -1){
    alert("127 Exists!")
}

//--- Like your example ---

String.prototype.includes = function(id){
    return this.split(/,/).indexOf(id) !== -1
}

if(str.includes("28")){
    alert("28 Exists!")
}
```

Comment: Don't add a method called `includes` to `String.prototype`, as that will be added to browsers in the next version of ECMAScript (the standard version of JavaScript): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it was like his example, but I did not know about ´includes´, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
str.split(',').indexOf('127');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [word boundary (`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/\b127\b/.test(str)
// => true
/\b1\b/.test(str)
// => false
```

Comment: This is a more generic approach than other answers and does not require the string to be converted to a different data format.